# How to increase text size of Disqus on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, tumblr, disqus

I have the free version of Disqus installed on my Tumblr website and everything is fine with it, except that the font size on mobile is microscopic. They don't allow you to edit much CSS on these things, but the thing needs to be readable on mobile screens. Here's  [my website](https://rachelmontano.com)

This is my Disqus HTML

```
{block:IfDisqusShortname}{block:PermalinkPage}
    <div class="disq">
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/embed.js"></script>
    <noscript><a href="https://{text:Disqus Shortname}.disqus.com/?url=ref">View the discussion thread.</a></noscript></div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}{/block:IfDisqusShortname}
```

Note that it's in a wrapper .disq. My media query is set for screens 992px wide and under. I've tried

```
.disq{font-size: 80px;}
```

and

```
#disqus_thread{font-size: 80px;}
```

and neither worked. Is there something I'm missing, or is this really how limited the free version is?

Comment: Disqus is loaded via an iframe and you cannot style content from another site. It's a CORS issue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing, the only option, I believe is if disqus have some paramters to change css on the version you are running on your blog

Comment: I've searched high and low on the Disqus end of things for available options and haven't found a thing, unfortunately. Didn't realize it was loaded via an iframe, that's frustrating. Thanks for the info!